# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, ajax

Espero me puedan ayudar con un error del que no soy capaz de ver la solución.
Dispongo de una funcion en JS que llama via AJAX a una url que a su turno me devuelve un json. Sin embargo, al ejecutar la funcion, la console me da el error

```
albaranes.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (albaran.js:124)
```

En el código de JS, he hecho un alert para comprobar que el contenido de las variables sea correcto y en el AJAX, lo he ejecutado forzando los valores y el resultado es tambien correcto.
Os adjunto los códigos por si me podeis ayudar.

Fichero Javascript

```
function mostrarCabeceraAlbaran(EjercicioAlbaran,NumeroAlbaran)
{
//alert(EjercicioAlbaran);
//alert(NumeroAlbaran);

$.post("../ajax/albaran.php?op=mostrarCabeceraAlbaran",
{EjercicioAlbaran : EjercicioAlbaran, NumeroAlbaran : NumeroAlbaran},
function(data, status)
{
data = JSON.parse(data);        <-LINEA DEL ERROR
mostrarform(true);

//Ocultar y mostrar los botones
$("#btnGuardar").hide();
$("#btnCancelar").show();
$("#btnAgregarArt").hide();
});

//$.post("../ajax/albaran.php?op=listarDetalle&id="+NumeroAlbaran,function(r){
//        $("#detalles").html(r);
//}
//);    
}
```

Fichero AJAX

```
case 'mostrarCabeceraAlbaran':
$sql=$albaran->mostrarCabeceraAlbaran($EjercicioAlbaran,$NumeroAlbaran);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

if( $stmt === false) {
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

$data= Array();
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH) ) {
$data[]=array(
"0"=>utf8_encode($row["CodigoCliente"]),
//"1"=>date_format($row["FechaAlbaran"], "d/m/Y"),
"1"=>utf8_encode($row["NumeroAlbaran"]),
"2"=>utf8_encode($row["NumeroFactura"]),
"3"=>utf8_encode(number_format($row["BaseImponible"], 2, ',', ' '))
);
}
$results = array(
"sEcho"=>1, //Información para el datatables
"iTotalRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros al datatable
"iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data), //enviamos el total registros a visualizar
"aaData"=>$data);

echo json_encode($results);
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
break;
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Si antes de la línea de error haces un console.log(data) ¿qué sale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al utilizar `json_encode()` en tu archivo php ya estas devolviendo un objeto a la petición AJAX, en tu script de javascript está de más el `data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: muchas gracias @eosfelipe . Tienes razón, la línea sobra. Agradezco mucho tu ayuda.

Comment: no es que el backend devuelva un objeto (no hay manera), el back siempre manda JSON (string). El que hace el parseo es Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas el `JSON.parse(data)`, ya que `data` no es un string, sino un object. jQuery ya parsea a un object la respuesta.

Ejecuta esto

```js
try {
  JSON.parse({}) // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err.message)
}
```

y entenderas lo que te digo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @emanuel-friedrich me ha servido de mucha ayuda